# Problem jquery ajax call,success function is not behaving properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made ajax call with jquery to get some information from database with php,but the problem is that when i am using `$.ajax` it is not working,it doesn't show any errors,it doesn't `console.log('success')` and i can't figure out why,while when i do the same thing with `$.post` it works.Any idea what is happening here?

```
function get_all_chats()
{   
    $.ajax({
        url: "get_previous_chats.php",
        type: "POST",
        succes: function(data){

            console.log(data);
            console.log("succes");
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.log(error);
        }
    })

    $.post("get_previous_chats.php", {}, function(data){
    console.log(data);
    })

}
```

Comment: $.post and $.ajax of post requests are both same, they are both made using the same underlying code which is XMLHTTPRequest , both works same way , in Ajax gives us more options to configure where as $.post is straightforward. Can you try adding debug points to your code and find out where the api call is stuck, also check your network tab in chrome browser to see if API is called, and what response you are getting from the php code..

Comment: Have you tried observing the requests in your browser's debugging tools to see if there's a difference. It looks like you're posting an empty object in your `$.post` request, but you're not posting any data in your `$.ajax` request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using ajax properly but there are properties that needs to be checked and apply. First is your 'success' where yours is 'succes' with a single S in the end. Next is you must throw request using 'data' property. So this is how it looks.

```
function get_all_chats()
{   
    $.ajax({
        url: "get_previous_chats.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: { data: YOUR_DATA  },
        success: function(data){

            console.log(data);
            console.log("succes");
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.log(error);
        }
    })

}
```

Comment: Thanks man,it was a typo on success and that's why it wasn't working.